# Using config files in MSTest (testConfig)

Tags: c#, unit-testing, testing, mstest, configuration-files

I´m trying to use MyProject.config in MSTest. I added this file in "Deployment" (testConfig).
What is the best practice to access those fields? Can i build something like Java Properties?

Example:

```
<host>localhost</host>
<port>0</port>
<user>me</user>
```

Edit:
 I have two Unit Test suite . I want to use diferents config files in each test.

Answer (score 1):

Is the [`ConfigurationManager.AppSettings`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.appsettings.aspx) property of any use? Give that a try and see if it works, like this:

```
string port = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("port");
```

You'd need to refactor your configuration file to be a standard "App.config" file, and you add key/value pairs like this:

```
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="port" value="80" />
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Comment: I know that i can use my App.config. I'm questioning when i need to use testconfig.